# BibTex-MLA not compliant with MLA?

Tags: biblatex, citing, mla-style, biblatex-mla

I'm having difficulty getting the output of `mla-new` to cite databases properly.

Here is my `*.bib` entry, pulled from EBSCOhost:

```
@article{social-media-family,
Author = {ÜNAL, Selime},
ISSN = {21461961},
Journal = {International Journal of Eurasia Social Sciences / Uluslararasi Avrasya Sosyal Bilimler Dergisi},
Keywords = {SOCIAL media, FAMILIES, VIRTUAL reality, ACQUISITION of data, aile iletişimi, facebook, family communication, Healthy communication, Sağlıklı iletişim, sanal iletişim, social media, sosyal medya, virtual communication, aile iletişimi, Sağlıklı iletişim, sanal iletişim, sosyal medya, FACEBOOK (Web resource)},
Number = {31},
Pages = {550 - 578},
Title = {The Effect of Social Media Ise to the Time Spent With Family Members},
Volume = {9},
url = {http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&AuthType=ip,sso&db=a9h&AN=129236793&site=ehost-live&scope=site&custid=s8356098},
Year = {2018},
urldate = {2018-02-28}
}
```

And my `*.tex` file bibliography setup is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla-new]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}

\defbibheading{bibliography}{\newpage\centering Works Cited}

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{first}{last}{Prof.}{class}{\today}{title}

Some info \autocite{social-media-family}.

\printbibliography
\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

The article database, `Academic Search Complete` is somehow being found at compile time and inserted after the link *(against MLA compliance)*:

[image: no description]

What can I do to move the `Academic Search Complete` (database field) to just before the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output of `biblatex-mla` does not adhere to MLA guidelines, please report this as a bug at https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/issues. Even though development of this package has stalled in recent years it is still good to have issues logged at one central place if development picks up speed again. It also helps users with a similar problem find the issue quicker.

You can modify one of the involved bibmacros a bit to make sure that the database component is written out before the URL if there is no `eprinttype`. The current definition can be found in [`mla-new.bbx`, ll. 355-366](https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/blob/9b1085ed3ff9eb6adbc13e1d915d4eee7aedce0f/mla-new.bbx#L355-L366). Essentially we print the `eprint` field before the URL and then clean it out to avoid printing it again if there is no `eprinttype`. A combination of `eprinttype`+`eprint` is usually associated with a full eprint identifier (JSTOR number, arXiv, ...) whereas a `eprint` without `eprinttype` just seems to signify the database. (It *might* have been nicer to choose a dedicated new field here...)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla-new]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro*{mla:container:one}{%
  \usebibmacro{mla:article:journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit%
  \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\space}%
     \printfield{eprint}
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \clearfield{eprint}%
     \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}%
    {}%
  \printunit{\addperiod\space}\newblock%
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{social-media-family,
  author  = {Ünal, Selime},
  journal = {International Journal of Eurasia Social Sciences / Uluslararasi Avrasya Sosyal Bilimler Dergisi},
  number  = {31},
  pages   = {550 - 578},
  title   = {The Effect of Social Media Ise to the Time Spent With Family Members},
  volume  = {9},
  url     = {http://search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&AuthType=ip,sso&db=a9h&AN=129236793&site=ehost-live&scope=site&custid=s8356098},
  year    = {2018},
  urldate = {2018-02-28}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some info \autocite{social-media-family}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ünal, Selime. “The Effect of Social Media Ise to the Time Spent With Family Members.” International Journal of Eurasia Social Sciences / Uluslararasi Avrasya Sosyal Bilimler Dergisi, vol. 9, no. 31, 2018, pp. 550–578. Academic Search Complete, search.ebscohost.com/login.aspx?direct=true&AuthType=ip,sso&db=a9h&AN=129236793&site=ehost-live&scope=site&custid=s8356098. Accessed 28 Feb. 2018.]

Comment: Tracked at https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/issues/19